# PHP get username from email address when using php_imap

Tags: php

I am connecting to a POP3 mailbox using PHP Imap, its connecting fine and i have this to receive my header info:

```
$header=imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);

        $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
        $toaddress=$header->toaddress;
        $replyto=$header->reply_to[0]->mailbox."@".$header->reply_to[0]->host;
        $datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$header->udate);
        $subject=$header->subject;
```

the `$toaddress` is showing `User Name <username@domain.com>`

how can i make it show just `username@domain.com`

for example, the actual email addresses are like 1234@domain.com and i need to retrieve the number only with nothing else

is this possible?

Comment: Probably because your question can be answered easily by reading the documentation. You didn't specify what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the "to" array from $header:

```
$email = $header->to[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->to[0]->host';
```

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imap-headerinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to work it out by using

```
$toaddress=$header->to[0]->mailbox."@".$header->to[0]->host;
```

Comment: This is exactly my answer...

Comment: sorry you must have answered just as i got it